# Find differences between two large tables in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, large-data

I have two different tables, say table A and B in oracle with around 15 million records in each. `Table A` has columns `(a,b,c,d)` and
`Table B` has columns `(e,f,g,h)`.

The objective is to  write a stored procedure to check if every record present in table A is also present in table B and vice versa. Differences between these two should be inserted into a third table.

My problem is that
 `column a` in `Table A` should be compared with concatenate of column e and f in table B if `column e` contains a certain string (0311),
 if not I have to compare it with just `column f`.

`Column b` should be compared with `column g` in `table B` and 
I also have to compare `column c` in the `table A` with `column g` in `table B`, if the two aren't a match `column d` should be compared with `column g`.

What's the fastest way to do so?

**for example these two are a match:**

```
Table A: 9353456789,03117884657,12082200003035,12082123595535
Table B: 9353456789,0311,7884657,12082200003035
```

or:

```
Table A: 9353456789,03117884657,12082200003035,12082123595535
Table B: 9353456789,0311,7884657,12082123595535
```

example of records that do not need concatenation and are a match:

```
Table A: 9353456789,03617884657,12082200003035,12082123595535
Table B: 9353456789,0361,03617884657,12082200003035
```

Comment: In general, you can find rows that are in `tableA` but not in `tableB` (assuming same/similar structures) with this query: `SELECT * FROM tableA MINUS SELECT * FROM tableB`. For your question though we'll need some more detail - could you post an example of 3-4 `TableA` rows and 3-4 `TableB` rows, including at least one row that would force a comparison by the concatenated value?

Comment: yes, for example these two are a match: Table A: 9353456789,03117884657,12082200003035,12082123595535
Table B: 9353456789,0311,7884657,12082200003035

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite enough to go on. Could you include at least one set of rows for each scenario (concatenate versus don't concatenate), and could you also identify columns `a`, `b`, `c`, ... `g`. Also, please specify what the "certain string" is that column `e` must contain. It would be best if you edited your question and added the examples rather than posting them in a comment. I'm pretty sure your question can be answered once it's defined well enough.

Comment: My guess is the user itself would find the answer, if he is able to explain his requirement. Please help us, to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a12d3/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( a VARCHAR2(20), b VARCHAR2(20), c VARCHAR2(20), d VARCHAR2(20) );
CREATE TABLE TableB ( e VARCHAR2(20), f VARCHAR2(20), g VARCHAR2(20), h VARCHAR2(20) );
CREATE TABLE TableC ( i VARCHAR2(20), j VARCHAR2(20), k VARCHAR2(20), l VARCHAR2(20) );

INSERT INTO TableA
          SELECT '9353456789','03117884657','12082200003035','12082123595535' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '9353456789','03617884657','12082200003035','12082123595535' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '9353456789','03617884657','12082200003034','12082123595534' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO TableB
          SELECT '9353456789','0311','7884657','12082200003035' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '9353456789','0311','7884657','12082123595535' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '9353456789','0361','03617884657','12082200003035' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '9353456789','0361','03617884657','12082200003036' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

To insert the rows - perform an `INSERT INTO... SELECT` using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between both tables using your requirements as the join condition; then for the rows which do not match either `TableA(a, b, c, d)` will all be `NULL` or `TableB(e, f, g, h)` will all be `NULL` and this can be used in the `WHERE` condition to only get the non-matched rows. Finally, so as not to return `NULL` values, `COALESCE()` is used for the returned values.

```
INSERT INTO TableC
    SELECT COALESCE( ta.a, tb.e ) AS i,
           COALESCE( ta.b, tb.f ) AS j,
           COALESCE( ta.c, tb.g ) AS k,
           COALESCE( ta.d, tb.h ) AS l
    FROM TableA ta
         FULL OUTER JOIN
         TableB tb
         ON (    ta.a = tb.e
             AND ta.b = CASE tb.f WHEN '0311' THEN tb.f || tb.g ELSE tb.g END
             AND ( ta.c = tb.h OR ta.d = tb.h )
            )
    WHERE ta.a IS NULL
    OR    tb.e IS NULL;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM TableC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a12d3/2/0)**:

```
|          I |           J |              K |              L |
|------------|-------------|----------------|----------------|
| 9353456789 | 03617884657 | 12082200003034 | 12082123595534 |
| 9353456789 |        0361 |    03617884657 | 12082200003036 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this as two statements, though it can be combined

```
Select a.* 
from tablea a left join tableb b on a.a = 
 case when e = 'string' then b.e || b.f else b.f end 
and ...
where b.e is null
```

The left join will return nulls where a row isn't found in table b, so this should bring up a list of rows i9n table a not in table b.  Change the statement to a right join and select b.* and you'll see whats in b but not in a.

Statement can be turned into a 'create table as' which will create a new table with the results from this select statement.

I put and ... your conditions there are a bit confusing, you'll just need to use case statements to pick which columns you want to compare/join on.

Comment: and how to import the result into another table? sorry but I'm really new in sql.

Comment: It's simple in oracle...putting CREATE TABLE new_table AS **put your select statement here**.  This will save the results of your query as a new_table (you can change use any name for the table in place of new_table)

Comment: I did a quick edit...concatonate in Oracle is done as field1 || field2  (or field1 || ' ' || field2 if you want the space between the two)